# Transferring data from queue to array

Tags: c

I'm trying to put integer data from each node in a queue into an array called arr. The data for each node is inputted by the user, say there's 5 nodes, and has 1 2 3 4 5, where node 1 stores a value of 1 and node 5 stores a value of 5. My code is below:

```
typedef struct linkedList {
  int val;
  struct linkedList *next;
} list;
```

I've tried doing the following but I'm getting a few warnings when I compile the code, I only included the body of the function and not the header or prototype and such.

```
  int i;
  int *arr;
  list *node = NULL;

  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    arr = node->id;
    node = node->next;
  }
```

The errors that I get are: `warning: assignment to ‘int *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast` and `warning: variable ‘arr’ set but not used`
How do I actually get the data from the queue into an array so that the array is `arr[0]=1` and `arr[4]=5]`? Thanks.

Comment: Those errors are fundamental. A good C text and exhaustive review of how pointers work, and how dynamic memory is managed, should probably be on your agenda. `arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` doesn't make sense (assigning an `int*` to an `int` within an indeterminate array, thus invoking undefined behavior), and `arr = node->id;` makes equally no sense (assigning `int` to an `int*`. Those warnings should be treated as gospel errors, because that's exactly what they are.

Comment: You're doing unnecessary allocations as well as not properly allocating to begin with, your code will result in undefined behavior/exceptions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The biggest challenge your code faces, as addressed by @Nina, is that your `arr` array should be contiguous in memory. This implies a single call to `malloc`, so not in a loop. If you do that, then set the spot in the array, not the array itself, to be the next item, then you're set i.e. `arr[i] = node->id`. This leaves you with rigid, functional code, assuming everything else works

Comment: Also if your question involves code it's best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible, Example as documented here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have your linked list allocated correctly and you know the number of nodes (since you didn't post the code for your linked list) then your copy to array function should look like this.

```c
int* copylist(struct LinkedList* ls,int numberofnodes){
    int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*numberofnodes);
    for(int index = 0; index < numberofnodes; ++index){
        arr[index] = ls->val;
        ls = ls->next;
    }
    return arr;
}
```